# On the number of involutions in some groups

Tags: finite-groups, symplectic-group, orthogonal-groups

How many involutions are there in $O_7(11)$ and $PSp_6(11)$ respectively? (Note that the sizes of the two groups mentioned here are the same.)

Comment: I would have thought GAP could handle this computationally. Altenatively, working out the conjugacy classes of involutions and their centralizers by hand does not seem out of reach.

Comment: How did you come to this question?

Comment: @ Lyons, the question is of interest to me because I am wondering whether there is a formula for determining the number of involutions in $O_{2n+1}(q)$ and $PSp_{2n}(q)$ respectively for $q$ odd and $n>2$. I actually expect someone to mention such formula in a comment or answer box if it exist. (With the help of some programming languages, I could determine the number of involutions in such groups of smaller orders...but inserting these in OEIS couldn't give me any reasonable sequence; so I am wondering if there is such a formula.) Thank you.

Comment: So, if you are interested in these quantities for general $q$ and hoped for someone to answer accordingly, why ask only about $q = 11$ (especially if you can compute it yourself)?

Comment: @user319994: There certainly is such a formula, which can in principle be worked out the way Geoff suggests. There is also the (slightly) different approach to observe that involutions arise from certain subspace configurations (of the $F_q$-space $V$ that $O(V)$ or $Sp(V)$ acts naturally on). Then count the number of such subspace configurations. Easier to count is the number of conjugacy classes of involutions: in $O_{2n+1}(q)$ there are $n$ classes, and in $PSp_{2n}(q)$ there are $1+[n/2]$.

Comment: @user319994: Centralizers of involutions in these groups are well understood. See for example Table 4.5.1 in Gorenstein-Lyons-Solomon, The Classification of the Finite Simple Groups, Amer. Math. Society Surveys and Monographs 40, Number 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $q$ be an odd prime power and say that $q\equiv\epsilon\pmod4$, where $\epsilon=\pm1$.

Using Geoff's suggestion I calculated the number of involutions in $\Omega_7(q)$ (the simple group; called $O_7(q)$ in the Atlas) to be
$$
\frac12 q^5(q^4+q^2+1)(q+\epsilon) + \frac12 q^6(q^4+q^2+1)(q^2+1) + \frac12 q^3(q^3+\epsilon).$$

The summands give the cardinalities of the three conjugacy classes.

In $PSp_6(q)$, the number of involutions is
$$q^4(q^4+q^2+1)+\frac12 q^6(q^3+\epsilon)(q^2+1)(q+\epsilon),$$
there being just two conjugacy classes.

Given the centralizer information I cited in my comment above, it is straightforward but laborious to work this out, or to work out $\Omega_{2n+1}(q)$ and $PSp_{2n}(q)$ for any $n>2$.  One can easily trip up getting the right power of $2$ in each summand.

I did check the answers against the Atlas for $q=3$.